# On the fp package: inverse sine function

Tags: fp

On page 3/7 of the  [fp package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fp) we see the definition of the inverse sine function as below:

```latex
\FParcsin#1#2 % #1 := arcsin(#2)
```

From high school we may remember: `Arcsin(0.5)=pi/6= 0.524 around`.
I got 0 for `Arcsin(0.5)` using `fp` package. Which is strange to me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
\FPdiv\pidivsix \FPpi 6 
\FParcsin \arcsinhalf 0.5 \\
\FParcsin \arcsinone 1 
Arcsin$(1)=\arcsinone$.\\
Arcsin$(\frac{1}{2})=\arcsinhalf$.\\
 This is a wrong answer the correct value is $\pidivsix$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm no TeX specialist, but it seems to me that here, `\frac{1}{2}` is not interpreted as a number, but as a string. A TeX specialist can explain this better than I can.

Comment: I used frac 1 2 as a text to type and did not deal with it as a number.

Comment: Try `\FParcsin \arcsinhalf{0.5}`. Otherwise your input is `\FParcsin \arcsinhalf{0}` and you are typesetting `.5`

Comment: Replace ```\FParcsin \arcsinhalf 0.5 \\``` with `\FParcsin \arcsinhalf {0.5}`. Apparently `fp` grabs the numbers like normal arguments. If you omit the braces, you only get `0`. You can already see that something fishy is going on on the input stage from the fact that the document typesets a spurious '.5'.

Comment: @cgnieder you gave me the correct answer. Would you write your answer below in the answer section then I accept it.

Comment: @Aria Indeed, you are right.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `$\arcsin(\frac{1}{2})=...$` instead of `Arcsin$(\frac{1}{2})=...$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX will interpret a string of digits (with optional sign and optional decimal point or comma) as a decimal number only if it *has* to, that is

> when it is looking for an explicit dimension, in which case the string representing a decimal number *must* be followed by one of the allowed units.

It's quite unfortunate that the documentation of `fp` presents the syntax in the shown form, because it *might* suggest resemblance to other programming languages that are more forgiving when numbers are involved.

Since TeX is mainly a typesetting program, it doesn't scan numbers except when it *has* to, but this can only happen when primitive commands are used, not with defined *macros* such as `\FParcsin`.

The suggestion `\FParcsin#1#2` means that `#1` and `#2` are standard arguments that therefore should be braced (unless they consist of a single token). So

```
\FParcsin{\arcsinhalf}{0.5}
```

is the correct syntax. This can be abbreviated into `\FParcsin\arcsinhalf{0.5}` because the first argument is a single token.

You could safely type `\FParcsin\arcsinone1`, but it's better to stick to a standard and type `\FParcsin\arcsinone{1}`, so the arguments are also visually clearer.

Similarly, you should stick to

```
\FPdiv\pidivsix{\FPpi}{6}
```

for the same reasons. The code `\FPdiv\pidivsix \FPpi 6` works, but if you try to compute pi over 10,

```
\FPdiv\pidivten \FPpi 10
```

would definitely *not* work and should be

```
\FPdiv\pidivten {\FPpi} {10}
```

or

```
\FPdiv\pidivten{\FPpi}{10}
```

Spaces are ignored when looking for an argument, so you have some freedom to suit your preferences.